# Expanding multiple rows in Angular SlickGrid cleans the row expand view of the earlier expanded rows

Tags: angular, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

I'm facing a issue with the Angular SlickGrid row detail feature, when I expand multiple rows and then come back to the earlier ones, they become blank.

I checked on the official demo page [here](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/rowdetail) and the issue persist there too.

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Go to example demo page [here](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/rowdetail)
2. Go to the table at bottom and first expand a row. Expanding row 6 here.
   [image]
3. Expand another row. Sometimes opening another row cleans the view of earlier row expand view.
   **Before expanding another row**:
   [image]
   **After expanding another row**:
   [image]
4. Otherwise, scroll a bit down, expand another row, scroll down more, expand another and then scroll up to check earlier expanded rows, it turns out the earlier ones becomes blank.
   [image]

It seems the library is caching the view or is not always able to maintain multiple view component. Although, I'm not sure.
I have tried to toggle these fields and used multiple combinations of these in row detail object,

```
rowDetailView: {
...
loadOnce: true,
saveDetailViewOnScroll: false,
useSimpleViewportCalc: true,
singleRowExpand: false,
...
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm the owner of the 6pac repo, which is the current official base repo. The expanding rows option is one I didn't write and don't officially support. I suspect there are quite a few gremlins lurking in there. @ghiscoding, the owner of the Angular repo might have more insight.

Comment: and I'm the owner of Angular-Slickgrid and I already replied to this on the same issue that you opened in Angular-Slickgrid [issue #546](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/issues/546#issuecomment-665629635).

Comment: I just added the question to make sure someone hasn't already found a solution. Plus, GIT also suggest to find questions on StackOverFlow before creating a bug/issue. Anyways I'll keep investigating the issues and will revert here if I'm able to solve it.

Comment: You're right, I'm pushing for any questions be asked on Stack Overflow instead of opening Github issues when it's not bug related.

Answer (score 0):

After spending couple of hours on this, I found the following 2 issues:

1. when passing a custom Id with `datasetIdPropName`, the Row Details were not refreshed at all
2. in some occasions opening a new Row Detail was blanking previous Row Detail

Both of these issues were found and fixed in separate PRs ([#550](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/pull/550) and [#552](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/pull/552))

The latest version [2.20.2](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/releases) now includes these fixes and the [Row Detail - Example](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/rowdetail) is now working as expected as well.

... so the Answer to your question is to just Update to latest version of Angular-Slickgrid

Comment: Hi! I tested this and found that the rows still appears blank once they reappear after scroll, but once we stop scrolling and start again to scroll, they reappear, so I think there is just some delay or the re-rendering is not done when they get in viewport. So I think this points me in the right direction. Thanks for the help. I'll try to make it full proof and will get back to you.

Comment: The way SlickGrid is built is to create/remove DOM elements for each row on the fly, there's also a buffer of 3 rows on top/bottom, SlickGrid only renders what is visible to the UI for performance reason. e.g. if the user can see 10 rows on the screen then SlickGrid renders 16 rows (10 + 3 + 3) and every time your scroll it removes hidden elements and creates new ones for the next visible rows... So anytime you scroll, the Row Detail needs to be re-rendered and that is what makes everything challenging, you can maybe try to increase the `minRowBuffer` grid option (default is `panelRows + 3`)